# Updating a table that has lock on its rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, locking

In SQL Server I am running the following SQL to lock a record first:

```
select *
from PATIENT with (updlock, rowlock, nowait)
where PA_ACCOUNT = 74988
```

Then afterwards in a different session I run the following update which freezes unless I add an index in PA_CYCLE field:

```
UPDATE PATIENT SET PA_CYCLE=3 WHERE PA_CYCLE=1
```

Even then the following update freezes:

```
UPDATE T1 SET PA_CYCLE=3 FROM PATIENT WHERE T1.PA_CYCLE=1 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UTILITY AS UT WHERE T1.PA_CLINIC = UT.UT_PATIENT AND UT.UT_KEY = 1)
```

Do we always have to have index on where clause fields in such scenarios and if yes then how can we resolve issue with the very last query?

FYI: There is no such record in our database matching where criteria to be updated so update is not even really waiting to update the locked record!

Comment: Why are you using such locking hints?

Comment: Well I'm coming from Oracle and there I would say "select .... for update nowait", and I thought thats the equivalent of such in sql server! What do I need to use if I want to lock the record and also get an error in case there is already another lock on it?

Comment: In SQL Server, you shouldn't need to add locks at all unless you have especially complex behaviour. It normally all done for you.

Comment: The fact the value doesn't *actually* exist is irrelevant, SQL Server doesn't know that. What problem is the locking hint on your select actually solving? All it's doing is reducing concurrency.

Comment: Without indexes you could end up with 2 tables scans, the first table scan will lock every row read because of your locking hints, so the second scan won't be able to start. Whereas with indexes, SQL Server can navigate directly to the required rows and only lock them rather than many un-necessary rows.

Comment: The way our application works is that when the user pulls up a patient record to modify, we lock the record until they are done with their modification. Meanwhile other users can query the record but won't be able to modify it.

Comment: That sounds like logic that should be implemented in the application, for example with a bitmap or flag to indicate the row is in use etc

Comment: Yeah as Stu says, you don't normally do that at the database level. Research optimistic or pessimistic locking.

Comment: You could probably work around it with RCSI isolation, but that's an unecessary overhead for an issue that shouldn't really exist - although is arguably the better isolation level.

Comment: @DaleK I went through the optimistic vs pessimistic locking and like I said in our application we are using pessimistic kind of locking. And as far as I know it is a very common practice (at least in Oracle) to lock the record when you are pulling it up in order to check the values and modify it. Now as Stu suggested we could have used an external mechanism to implement the locking and isolation but again as far as I know It is very common to delegate this task to database because database is kind of a central server/hub in client/server architecture. That being said in Oracle we wouldn't ...

Comment: @DareK have any problem because it would recognize that the update doesn't need to touch the locked record, but apparently that is not the case in Sql Server or maybe there is a way that I'm not aware of it. Would you please let me know if I have to use any other hint or way of locking or something else?

Comment: AFAIK (and I could be wrong), you wouldn't normally use database locks for this kind of thing, because as you have already noted, the behaviour might not be consistent depending on indexes, and order of locks taken etc. You would normally find the record you need and update a column in it to say its locked.

Comment: @DaleK But then "Atomicity" is not guaranteed. Let's say user A reads the record and realizes the record is not locked. Right before User A updates the lock field to lock the record, user B reads the same thing and he/she makes the same judgment, hence both think they have their exclusive locks and update the same record, isn't it?

Comment: I also have never tried to implement this kind of control over the database - at least in the SQL Server world this is frowned upon, locks are an internal mechanism used to ensure concurrency, atomicity and consistency. with suitable indexing and using `readpast` you *might* get it working but I think it would be a real pain point.

Comment: @alpal you write your "check-out" SQL to check and update the locked column in one exclusive transaction, i.e. the first person to start gets an exclusive lock while they determine what they need to do.

Comment: @DaleK And how would you get that exclusive lock? Does it have to be mentioned in the beginning of transaction? or elsewhere?

Comment: @alpal one could google ["sql server implementing pessimistic locking"](https://convincedcoder.com/2018/09/01/Optimistic-pessimistic-locking-sql/#pessimistic-locking)

Comment: @DaleK Thank you

Comment: “Just” enable RCSI. It’s as close to Oracle’s “writers don’t block readers” as SQL Server can get. Pessimistic locking is a legitimate practise, but you will find that a lot of SQL Server development is done avoiding transactions which cover multiple statements, this is due to the traditional locking done in SQL Server which makes anything more complex than a one row update a nightmare.

Comment: @AndrewSayer Thanks I will check out RCSI which is also suggested by Stu.

Comment: @DaleK I enabled RCSI, but it still prevents "update patient set pa_cycle=1 where pa_account=625" to run even though (as can be seen in the first sql) the locking query has locked a record with different pa_account!

Comment: @alpal you tagged the wrong person - I know nothing about RCSI...

Comment: @DaleK Sorry and thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: @AndrewSayer I enabled RCSI, but it still prevents "update patient set pa_cycle=1 where pa_account=625" to run even though (as can be seen in the first sql) the locking query has locked a record with different pa_account!

Comment: It doesn't fail, it gets blocked and waits to acquire an X lock on the table because you are saying update all rows in the table, including the ones currently locked by another transaction. `update patient with (readpast)...` Or at least it does with `where 1=1` like you previous had.